# Periodically update the values in the database using spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a leave management system where the employees leave quota includes the number of leaves of each leave type(eg: annual, sick) that the employees can obtain each year. I need the leave quota of each employee to be updated to the original value(fixed amount of leave each employee is eligible for) at the beginning of every year. How can I implement this using spring boot and mysql as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re looking for automatic process, you can use Spring scheduler with cron job. Check this https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was not the answer I was expecting. But it helped me to get an idea and build my answer.

Comment: It’s my pleasure, you can share your thought also if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Many applications like yours have end-of-year programs.  Someone in your HR / accounting / finance  department runs them as part of the task of closing the previous year's books and opening the new year's.

Your quota-reset function belongs there. Your kind of system may also have end of quarter, end of month, and / or end-of-week programs.

How do you implement these programs?  The same way as you implement other data-handling programs. If your system is a web app, its administrator page will contain a "close last year, start new year" button.

For safety, it's probably best to prompt a user who presses the button like this.

> "Are you sure you want to close calendar year 2019 and open calendar year 2020? You cannot undo this. To proceed, please re-enter your password."

Comment: Yes the quota reset function belongs to the HR. As you mentioned the program makes a report at the end of each quarter. The report includes the number of leaves taken and the remaining leaves. And yes I thought of using that button option.